# App keeps restarting after Exception

Tags: android, exception

I have created a class called `AppContext` and registered it in my manifest

```
 <application
    android:name=".application.AppContext"
```

In this class, I have the following code:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(this));
}
```

The `ExceptionHandler`-class contains the following code:

```
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
        Intent exceptionIntent = new Intent(context, ExceptionActivity.class);
        exceptionIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
        context.startActivity(exceptionIntent);
        System.exit(1);
```

To test it, I have created a function in an random activity , which calls

```
Log.d("", null);
```

and throws a `NullpointerException`.

It works, if an exception occurs, the ExceptionActivity  is showing. But the app keeps restarting after throwing the exception. In 2 of 3 times, the restarting activity  overlays the ExceptionActivity.
How can I prevent it? if an exception occurs, I want the user to restart the app manually. Thank you!

Comment: Just a guess, but some of your exceptions are very likely to not be "uncaught" and will handle the exception themselves, no?

Comment: Sorry, my english ist not the best. I don't get your comment :( What do you mean by "not be "uncaught" and will handle the exception themselves" ?

Comment: You are using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` which will set the exception handler for all exceptions that aren't caught. A lot of processes will catch their exceptions, you are just catching the remaining exceptions that aren't already being caught. Sorry, it is hard to say it simply.

Comment: @zgc7009 I think the point of this is to show the user a screen if the app has crashed. If an exception is caught, the app won't crash.

Comment: Ok now I understand it. The nullpointerexception is definitively not caught, because the uncaughtException is called and the ExceptionActivity is started. But the app is also restarting at the same time

Comment: In my experience, when an app crashes, Android tries to restart it with the last Activity removed from the stack. For example, if you enter an app on Activity A and navigate to Activity B, then Activity B crashes, the app will be relaunched and you will be on Activity A (Activity B is no longer on the stack). I remember reading about this behavior but cannot recall where it's documented.